# In Blazor MAUI, how can we change the color of navigation area

Tags: blazor, maui, .net-maui.shell

In Blazor MAUI, how can we change the color of navigation area to Pink? I'm initially focused on **Android**.

```
  <Shell BackgroundColor="Pink">
    <TabBar  
      Shell.TabBarTitleColor="#072644"
      Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="White"
      Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="Red"
      Shell.TabBarDisabledColor="Green"
      Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray">
```

Here is the Minimal Reproducible repository: https://github.com/johnmangam/NavBarColor

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the navigation area in Blazor MAUI, you need to override the `OnCreate()` under **Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs** and then set `Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Pink);` like below:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      
        Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Pink);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @John Thanks for your update, I've tested it, it did work on my side, you can see the screenshot above. Can you help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post?

Comment: Thank you @AlexandarMay 

https://github.com/johnmangam/NavBarColor is the reproducible repository.

Comment: @John No worries, I can reproduce your issue. Please remove the extra parameter `PersistableBundle persistentState` in your OnCreate() and make the method protected as I posted, this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for catching that and helping. If possible, could you take a look at the other issue too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145280/in-blazor-maui-with-a-shared-ui-library-navigation-doesnt-work

Comment: You are welcome! Your another issue has been taken care of.