# In Blazor MAUI with a shared UI library, navigation doesn't work

Tags: blazor, maui, .net-maui.shell

In a **shared blazor library**, **login page** and **sample page** are defined.

Here is the Minimum Reproducible Example: https://github.com/johnmangam/ShellNavigation/

**Login.razor**

```
@page "/login"

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<button @onclick="onclick"></button>

@code {
    private void onclick()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/sample");
    }
}
```

**Sample.razor**

```
@page "/sample"

...
```

The above two pages that are created in the shared razor library are made use in a **blazor maui project** as shell tabbar shellcontents as shown below.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.MainPage>
  <Shell >
    <TabBar>
      <Tab >
        <ShellContent Title="Login" Route="login">
          <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ContentPage Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
                <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                  <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type sharedlibrarypages:Login}" />
                  </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                </BlazorWebView>
              </ContentPage>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        </ShellContent>
      </Tab>

      <Tab Title="Sample">
        <Tab.Icon>
          <FontImageSource Size="24"
        FontFamily="material-icons"
        Glyph="{x:Static icons:MaterialIcons.Sample}"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Sample" Route="sample">
          <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ContentPage>
                <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                  <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type sharedlibrarypages:Sample}" />
                  </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                </BlazorWebView>
              </ContentPage>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        </ShellContent>
      </Tab>
...
```

To register their routes, I've done this in the MauiProgram.cs

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts => {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont( "MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf", "material-icons");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
        
        //builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        //I've done this to enable routing - not sure about these

        builder.Services.AddTransient<Login>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<Sample>(); 
 

        Routing.RegisterRoute("/login", typeof(Login));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("/sample", typeof(Sample));
       
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

When the app is running, the Login page from the shared library is visible and when I click the button, the **Navigate code executes but it is not navigating.**

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Thank you @JessieZhang-MSFT Here is the MRE: https://github.com/johnmangam/ShellNavigation/

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I tested it in the Android platform and found that the navigation isn't working, thank you.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT it is basically not able to resolve the routes as the razor pages are in shared library. Do we need to do something special in the shared library scenario?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Could you suggest the approach I could take to resolve this navigation?

Comment: For this problem, you can also create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I also found a similar issue, you can check it here: [.NET MAUI Blazor NavigationManager may not work correctly on Window](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8458).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thank you so much.